# PRS-4 - Why does Class 'App\\TgHelpers\\TelegramCommandsProcess' not found?

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

The structure of my project is as follows:

[image]

`Handler.php` is input script. Here is its beginning:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use \App\TgHelpers\TelegramCommandsProcess;
$tgProcessor = new TelegramCommandsProcess();
```

All scripts are in the same namespace - App. An error is displayed in the logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\\TgHelpers\\TelegramCommandsProcess' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the autoload field in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "testVersionTelegramForecast//"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you try with use App\TgHelpers\TelegramCommandsProcess; instead of use \App\TgHelpers\TelegramCommandsProcess;

Comment: @WebArtisan, already tried. Result is the same

Answer (score 4):

the register must match `\App\TgHelpers\ => project/TgHelpers`,

`composer.json` should be at the root of your project

```
project/
   tgHelpers/
      TelegramCommandsProcess.php
   Handler.php
composer.json
vendor/
      autoload.php
```

In  Handler.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: you took it into account "the register must match \App\TgHelpers\ => project/TgHelpers" ?

Comment: not sure that completely understood you question, but, i suppose, yes

Comment: The tgHelpers folder should be called TgHelpers if the namespace is \TgHelpers

Comment: changed folder name but it did't help